Formatting numbers and percentages as text in quarto/rmarkdown
When writing in Quarto, I sometimes would like to format numbers/percentages as text. For example, when starting a sentence with a number or when a percentage is easily expressed in words. Here are some sample sentences:

Forty-two is the magic number. (instead of: 42 is the magic number.)
Half are here. (instead of: 50% are here.)

Using the {papaja} package, I am able to format "plain" numbers as desired, e.g.:
papaja::printnum(42L, numerals = FALSE, capitalize = TRUE)
#> [1] "Forty-two"

However, I haven't found a way to format percentages as text. Here are some attempts (and errors) with {papaja}:
try(
  papaja::printnum(0.5, numerals = FALSE, capitalize = TRUE)
)
#> Error in formatC(numerals = FALSE, capitalize = TRUE, digits = 2L, format = "f",  : 
#>   unused arguments (numerals = FALSE, capitalize = TRUE)

try(
papaja::printnum(25/50, numerals = FALSE, capitalize = TRUE)
)
#> Error in formatC(numerals = FALSE, capitalize = TRUE, digits = 2L, format = "f",  : 
#>   unused arguments (numerals = FALSE, capitalize = TRUE)

try(
  papaja::printp(0.5, numerals = FALSE, capitalize = TRUE)
)
#> Error in papaja::printp(0.5, numerals = FALSE, capitalize = TRUE) : 
#>   unused arguments (numerals = FALSE, capitalize = TRUE)

Created on 2024-09-15 with reprex v2.1.1
I appreciate any suggestions for packages or code to make pretty textual percentages!

If you look at the printnum help (?papaja::printnum()), you'll see that numerals = TRUE is only available as a method for an integer object.
You can use the numbers_to_words (or shorter n2w) function from the xfun package instead:
xfun::numbers_to_words(0.5, cap = TRUE)
# [1] " point five"
xfun::n2w(25/50, cap = TRUE)
# [1] " point five"

Note that capitalize does not work in this case... That might be reported as an issue to the package.
I don't think you can get the second example working (to get Half as a result) unless by writing your own custom function to handle the special case where the value to convert would be 0.5, something like:
n2w_custom = function(x, ...) {
  if (x == 0.5) {
    return("Half")
  } else {
    xfun::n2w(x, ...)
  }
}


As mentioned by @julien.leroux5, this feature is currently only supported for integers, but it's pretty straight forward to extend use what we have to support decimals (note that printnum is now an alias for apa_num:
decimal_to_words <- function(x, capitalize = FALSE) {
  shortcut <- NULL
  if(x == 0) shortcut <- "no"
  if(x == 1) shortcut <- "all"
  if(x == 0.5) shortcut <- "half"

  if(!is.null(shortcut)) {
    if(isTRUE(capitalize)) shortcut <- papaja:::capitalize(shortcut)
    return(shortcut)
  }

  fraction <- MASS::fractions(x)
  numbers <- strsplit(as.character(fraction), "/", fixed = TRUE)[[1]] |>
    as.integer()

  numerator <- papaja::apa_num(as.integer(numbers[1]), numerals = FALSE, capitalize = capitalize)
  
  denominator <- dplyr::case_when(
    numbers[2] == 3 ~ "third"
    , numbers[2] == 4 ~ "quarter"
    , numbers[2] == 5 ~ "fifth"
    , .default = {
      den <- papaja::apa_num(as.integer(numbers[2]), numerals = FALSE)
      den <- paste0(den, "th")
      den
    }
  )
  
  if(numbers[1] > 1) denominator <- paste0(denominator, "s")
  denominator <- gsub(" ", "-", denominator)
  
  paste(numerator, denominator, sep = " ") |>
  gsub(",", "", x = _)
}

Consider the following examples:
r$> decimal_to_words(0)                           
[1] "no"

r$> decimal_to_words(1)                           
[1] "all"

r$> decimal_to_words(0.5, capitalize = TRUE)      
[1] "Half"

r$> decimal_to_words(3/4, capitalize = TRUE)      
[1] "Three quarters"

r$> decimal_to_words(4/5)                         
[1] "four fifths"

r$> MASS::fractions(0.2486)                       
[1] 1243/5000

r$> decimal_to_words(0.2486)                      
[1] "one thousand two hundred and forty-three five-thousandths"

r$> decimal_to_words(round(0.2486, 2))            
[1] "one quarter"

We may add support for this in papaja.
